# Confusion about how to process lines in a text file as they are read

Tags: java

So I was given the following GradedActivity class:

```
 public class GradedActivity   
 {   
private double score;  // Numeric score   

public void setScore(double s)
{
    if (s < 0)
    score = 0.0;
else if (s > 100)
    score = 100.0;
    else
        score = s;
 }

public double getScore()
{
   return score;
}


   public char getGrade()
  {   
     char letterGrade;  

  if (score >= 90)
     letterGrade = 'A';
  else if (score >= 80)
     letterGrade = 'B';
  else if (score >= 70)
     letterGrade = 'C';
  else if (score >= 60)
     letterGrade = 'D';
  else
     letterGrade = 'F';

  return letterGrade;
} }
```

and I was tasked with generating a constructor that accepts values for points Obtaned and pointsTotal as arguments, initializes them, and sets the corresponding score (points obtained divided by points total), accessors and mutators for pointsobtained and total.

So here is what I came up with:

```
public class ProgrammingAssignment extends GradedActivity 
{
   public int pointsObtained;
   public int pointsTotal;

   public ProgrammingAssignment(int p, int t)
   {

      pointsObtained = p;
      pointsTotal = t;
   } 

   public int getPointsObtained()
   {
      return pointsObtained;
   }

   public int getPointsTotal()
   {
      return pointsTotal;
   }

   public double getScore()
   {
     return pointsObtained / pointsTotal;
   }

   public void setPointsObtained(int p)
   {
  pointsObtained = p;
}

 public void setPointsTotal(int t)
 {
    pointsTotal = t;
 }     
 }
```

Everything compiles without error, but getScore isn't computing obtained/total (it comes back 0) in my test class:

```
 public class PADemo
 {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        ProgrammingAssignment p1 = new ProgrammingAssignment(28,30);
            GradedActivity p2 = new ProgrammingAssignment(0,30);

      System.out.println (p1.getPointsObtained());
      System.out.println (p1.getPointsTotal());
      System.out.println (p1.getScore());  
      System.out.println (p1.getGrade());  

      System.out.println (p2.getScore());  
      System.out.println (p2.getGrade());  

      p1.setPointsObtained(25);
      p1.setPointsTotal(40);
      System.out.println (p1.getScore());  
      System.out.println (p1.getGrade() == 'F');  
 }
 }
```

How do I obtain the score (points obtained/points total) with getScore()

Test class returns:

28
30
0.0
F
0.0
F
0.0
true

Comment: In the beginning. there is duplicate arrival `a Z23YTU`, is it correct?  Maybe it's worth to test with less obfuscated data?

Comment: I think your code is getting things reasonably right. There may be some bugs but they are not particularly obvious. I see that the first car to arrive is A123TR and you say that your code is not handling departures as yet. On that basis, I would expect A123TR to still be in the garage once the file has been fully read in. However, your expectation of which cars should be in the garage does not include A123TR. This makes me think your expected list of cars in the garage includes the departures that you haven't yet implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough description of your problem.

Comment: @Alex Rudenko It's supposed to remove it if there's a duplicate, but I havent gotten to that part just yet

Comment: @Simon Yes, A123TR is to arrive first, followed by 3 more cars, then leave, but it's showing it in the garage and the queue, as if it's processing the text file all at once and not in a sequential order

Comment: A123TR is showing in the garage as "d A123TR" because that car's departure is being inserted into the garage by the `else` branch of the `if(line.contains("a ")) {` condition.

Comment: Arrivals are being processed by both the constructor and the `arrival()` function.

Comment: @Simon So how can I process them sequentially?

Comment: At present you have a loop in your constructor that processes all the cars sequentially. Then after all the cars have been processed sequentially, you add them using the `arrival()` function in your main program -- as literal strings rather than as strings read from the 'parking.txt' file. You'll want to choose to do one or the other -- not both.

Comment: I notice that you use ``line.contains("a ")`` to read the command. I would have used ``line.startWith("a ")``.

Answer (score 1):

> Cars waiting: [a A123TR, a Z23YTU, a R23EWQ, a ERW345, a B12GFT...

Does that look correct? Why would you have the "a " at the beginning? That is not part of the car license. The "a " and "d " need to be removed BEFORE you add the license to the garage or queue.

> creates a stack for cars in a garage (Max of 7)

> a queue for cars waiting (max of 5)

Your basic logic appears wrong (to me).

When you get an "a" you do one of two things:

1. if there are less than 7 cars in the garage you add the car to the garage.
2. If there are 7, then if then are less the 5 cars in the queue, you add the car to the "queue".

When you get a "d" you:

1. first remove the car from the "garagee",
2. then you check the "queue". If there are cars in the "queue" then you move the car from the "queue" to the "garage".

So the logic might be structure something like:

```
while (...)
{
    ...
    String[] data = line.split(" ");

    if (data[0].equals("a"))
        processArrival( data[1] );
    else if (data[0].equals("d"))
        processDeparture( data[1] );
}
```

1. I used the String.split(...) method which was suggested in your last question because it is a better test then to test the whole String for a specific character and your two pieces of data are separated into the array ready for processing. The data will now be split into two pieces of data: a) function
   b) license
2. I used separate methods because the code is easier to read and logic for each function is contained in individual methods.

Comment: No that is NOT what I suggested. Your logic is first based on the "a" or "d" code, not the number of cars in the parking garage. To better structure your code create methods like: `processArrival(line)` and `processDeparture(line)`. Then if those methods you implement the logic as suggested above.

Comment: Also, your code is passing the "line" to the methods but you are then treating the line as the "license". Well, the line still contains the "a ERW345" or "d ERW345", so you will never find a match when you try to compare the departure license.

Comment: What didn't help? What don't you understand? Where are your follow up questions? The suggestions given are for a newbie to understand but you have to follow the suggestions? You were given pseudo code. Why does your posted code first check the length of the garage when you were given code that shows how to check for "a" or "d" first??? What don't you understand that "a" and "d" are NOT part of the license plate and should not be stored ? Again you were given code showing how to separate the "function" from the "license".

Comment: You original question about "processing lines in a text file as they are read" has indeed been answered. You can only solve one problem at a time, so yes, there may still be other problems but at least your code is now better structured and will allow for better debugging since the major flaws in your logic have been fixed.

Comment: I showed you how to split the input line into two pieces of data.  Do you not see the `split(...)` method? This was code you were given in your last question (you accepted the wrong answer!) 1) The code then checks the first item in the array for the "a" or "d". Then the code passes the second item in the array (ie. the "license")  to the processing methods? 2) You called your methods "arrival" and "departure". I added "processing" to make the method name more descriptive.

Comment: I provided simple answers to your problem. I provided basic working code for you to structure your code. Where did you make a comment stating you didn't understand my suggestions? You did NOT respond to my suggestions until I pressed for you to explain what you found confusing. I then took the time to go into more detail about my suggestions. When we provide advice we assume that you will actually try the posted code and then either 1) "accept" the question indicating the advice was helpful, so others reading the question know the problem has been solved or 2) ask follow up questions.